# Define $a \sim b$ if $a - b$ is an integer in $\Bbb R$. Show that ${}\sim{} $ is an equivalence relation. Show the classes of equivalence as well.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Define $a  \sim  b$ if $a - b$ is an integer in $\Bbb R$. Show that  ${}\sim{} $  is an equivalence relation. Show the classes of equivalence as well.

Here's my work. Am I correct? I also do not understand how to find equivalence classes.

Reflexive: $ a\sim  a$ -> a - a; so  ${}\sim{} $ is reflexive.

Symmetric: $a  \sim   b -> a - b$ then $b  \sim  a -> b - a$; so  ${}\sim{} $  is symmetric.

Transitive: $a  \sim   b -> a - b$ and $b \sim  c -> b - c$ then $a - c$ so $a  \sim  c$; so   ${}\sim{} $    is transitive.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  For reflexive, I would write "$a-a=0$ is an integer, so $a\sim a$"

Comment: $a-a$ is not a statement, so it makes no sense to say that something implies it; each of your three lines has the same problem..

Comment: The equivalence classes are of the form $$[a]_\sim=\{b\mid a-b\in\Bbb Z\}.$$

Comment: How would I correct my work for symmetric and transitive? I get that for reflexive a - a = 0 so it can imply a ~ a, but I have no way of knowing what a - b is or b - a is.

Comment: You have presented no work. What you wrote means nothing. Please read the comment by Brian M. Scott, which was upvoted 7 times.

Comment: Would this be correct? 
R: a ~ a as a - a = 0
S: a ~ b as a - b = k and b ~ a as b - a = -k
T: a ~ b as a - b = k and b ~ c as b - c = l so a - c = k + l meaning a ~ c

Classes: 
[0] = {1-1, 2-2, 3-3...}
[1] = {1-0, 2-1, 3-2,...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the equivalence classes, each has a *unique* representative in $[0,1)$, so the the set of equivalence classes is
$$\{x+\mathbf Z\mid 0\le x<1 \}. $$
THis set is usually denoted $\mathbf R/\mathbf Z$ and is called the one-dimensional torus.

Comment: One-dimensional torus aka circle :D

Comment: Not quite: it has some more structure than the plain circle – rather  the special unitary group $U(1)$.

Comment: It's a terminological difference, then. When I say circle, I think of the Lie group. To be honest, this is the first time I hear of this difference.

Comment: For me, a circle, without context, is just a geometric object.